# Changing the current graph of tf.placeholder objects in Tensorflow: Is it possible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In my code, I am changing my current default graph for some reason and rebuild all the computation logic from scratch. This naturally leads to some errors, since my `tf.placeholder` items stay in the old graph. I can naturally declare these again, but in order to do that, I have to write a lot of glue-junk code which will needlesly complicate everything. What I need is to get all `tf.placeholder` objects in my current graph and then transfer to them into the new graph I am going to create. Is there any way to do that? My preliminary research did not give any meaningful results but I am highly positive there should be a way to do this in Tensorflow.

Comment: One thing you can do is to get all the nodes with name 'placeholder' from trained check point or frozen graph.

But why is that important? You can simple declare new place holders with same shape in your new graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2 graphs, you can copy operations and variables from a graph to the other using the [`tf.contrib.copy_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/copy_graph) module.

In particular, you can use the [`copy_op_to_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/copy_graph/copy_op_to_graph) to copy the placeholder `pl` from graph `g1` to graph `g2`:

```
tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_op_to_graph(
    pl,
    g2,
    [],
    scope=''
)
```