# How to use tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_op_to_graph()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm using `tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_op_to_graph()` to copy an operation from `g1` to `g2`.

Edited code:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 1, TIME_STEP = 2
def noise_rnn(self, BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEP):
    with tf.variable_scope("noise_rnn", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer()):
        gaussianNoiseRnnInputList=[]
        for batch in range(BATCH_SIZE):
            gaussianNoiseInputList=[]
            for i in range(TIME_STEP):
                gaussianNoiseInput = tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1, 1, 10], mean=0, stddev=tf.sqrt(0.6))
                gaussianNoiseInputList.append(gaussianNoiseInput)
                gaussianNoiseInput = tf.concat(gaussianNoiseInputList, axis=1, name='gaussianNoiseInput_concat')
            gaussianNoiseRnnInputList.append(gaussianNoiseInput)
        gaussianNoiseRnnInput = tf.concat(gaussianNoiseRnnInputList, axis=0, name='gaussianNoiseRnnInput_concat')
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(10)
        hiddens, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=gaussianNoiseRnnInput, dtype=tf.float32)
        return hiddens

with noiseGraph.as_default():
    gaussianRnnOutput = speech2vid.noise_rnn(BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEP)
    BATCH_SIZE_copy = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(BATCH_SIZE, g2)
    TIME_STEP_copy = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(TIME_STEP, g2)
    gaussianRnnOutput_copy = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_op_to_graph(gaussianRnnOutput, g2, [])
```

New error when `copy_variable_to_graph(BATCH_SIZE, g2)`:

```
TypeError: 1(BATCH_SIZE) is not a Variable.
```

If I comment the following two lines:

```
BATCH_SIZE_copy = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(BATCH_SIZE, g2)
TIME_STEP_copy = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(TIME_STEP, g2)
```

I get another error:

```
......
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 200, in copy_op_to_graph
    for x in op.inputs]
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 172, in copy_op_to_graph
    new_op = copy_op_to_graph(op, to_graph, variables, scope)
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 200, in copy_op_to_graph
    for x in op.inputs]
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 172, in copy_op_to_graph
    new_op = copy_op_to_graph(op, to_graph, variables, scope)
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 200, in copy_op_to_graph
    for x in op.inputs]
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 172, in copy_op_to_graph
    new_op = copy_op_to_graph(op, to_graph, variables, scope)
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 200, in copy_op_to_graph
    for x in op.inputs]
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 172, in copy_op_to_graph
    new_op = copy_op_to_graph(op, to_graph, variables, scope)
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 200, in copy_op_to_graph
    for x in op.inputs]
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 172, in copy_op_to_graph
    new_op = copy_op_to_graph(op, to_graph, variables, scope)
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py", line 200, in copy_op_to_graph
    for x in op.inputs]
  File "/media/data2/liuhan/envs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1879, in inputs
    return Operation._InputList(self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Actually, I do not know how to use this function. Some one can explain the third param `[]` in the function for me? And how to solve this error?

Thank you!

I saw an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705666/changing-the-current-graph-of-tf-placeholder-objects-in-tensorflow-is-it-possib/53710720#53710720). But I do not know the meaning of `[]`?

**EDIT:** Edit code and errors.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/copy_graph/python/util/copy_elements.py), it seems that the `variables` argument is used to retrieve already copied variables:

```
#Extract names of variables
copied_variables = dict((x.name, x) for x in variables)

#If a variable by the new name already exists, return the
#correspondng tensor that will act as an input
if new_name in copied_variables:
    return to_graph.get_tensor_by_name(copied_variables[new_name].name)
```

However the following lines retrieve copied variables (or ops/tensors) as well:

```
try:
    already_present = to_graph.as_graph_element(
        new_name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=True)
    return already_present
except:
    pass
```

So my guess is that you can pass an empty list as third argument.

The simplified code you presented is not enough to understand what's your problem is, but in general, `copy_op_to_graph()` takes operation or tensor (if it is a tensor, then it is an output of some unerlying operation) as input and copies it to a new graph. If it has variables as inputs you should copy those variables using `copy_variable_to_graph()` before you attempt to copy an op. Take a look at this example of copying two variables and addition operation to a new graph:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var1 = tf.Variable(2*tf.ones([2, 2]), name='var1')
var2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 2]), name='var2')
add_tensor = tf.add(var1, var2)

to_graph = tf.Graph() # graph where everything above will be copied to

var1_copied = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(var1, to_graph)
var2_copied = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_variable_to_graph(var2, to_graph)

add_tensor_copied = tf.contrib.copy_graph.copy_op_to_graph(add_tensor, to_graph, [])

with tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph()) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(add_tensor.eval())
    # [[3. 3.]
    # [3. 3.]]

with tf.Session(graph=to_graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(add_tensor_copied.eval())
    # [[3. 3.]
    # [3. 3.]]
```

Comment: According to what you said "If it has variables as inputs you should copy those variables using copy_variable_to_graph() before you attempt to copy an op." I realized I do have some inputs, but my inputs are not tensorflow variables, and I get another error. I'm sorry I didn't show a clear code. I have edited my question.

Comment: I have updated my code and error. Two 'int' are passed to the function. Is there any variables needed to be copied to `g2` before copying variables? Thank you very much. You really helped!

Comment: `BATCH_SIZE` and `TIME_STEP` are not part of tensorflow graph and they aren't variables. You can't copy them. You first need to create `gaussianRnnOutput` and then you will be able to copy it. But again, to copy the whole graph it is not that trivial. You need to copy variables and ops individually. Take a look at [this code](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/recursively-copying-elements-from-one-graph-to-another-in-tensorflow/) that takes care of recursive copy. It may not be compatible with every tensorflow version, but It for certain compatible with `tensorflow==1.9`.

Comment: + you should mention in your question that it has been edited and provide the original version of your question.